# Python не записывает данные в файл

Tags: python

При окончании программы, python создает accounts.txt, но он пустой. Подскажите в чем проблема

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://*****.************.***/****/")
driver.execute_script("window.open('','_blank');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.get("https://*******.**")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[2]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/ul/li[2]/a').click()
mail_pass = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="restore-get"]/pre').text

filename = "accounts.txt"
mpff = str(mail_pass)
f = open(filename, "w")
f.write("Почта & пароль : " + mpff + ";" + "\n")
```

Comment: Попробуйте закрыть файл до завершения программы.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По умолчанию данные пишутся в буфер. Если данных не много, то буфер не сбрасывается автоматически и данные не отдаются системе до тех пор пока файл не закроется или вы явно `file.flush()` не вызовите.

Чтобы автоматически закрывать файл, используйте with-конструкцию:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.write(text)
```

Если использовать [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use), то в одну строчку можно записать текст в файл:

```
Path(filename).write_text(text)
```